# Running pc only scanners in Paralllels Desktop VM using a macbook air (late 2015)?

Tags: macbook-pro, parallels-desktop, scanning

I want to use Kodak ScanMate i1190WN with my MBA late 2015. This is a pc only scanner and no driver for mac os are available.  Can this scanner be able to work with a Parallels Desktop VM in my macbook?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be able to?

Comment: I use a Zune music player and sync it to a Win10 running on a VM so I don't see why you can't do the same with a scanner.  How about giving it a shot and *answering* your own question with the results?